# Web API with Python Flask POST request 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: python-3.x, request

I am making a Web API for a Python program I wrote, I am copying a tutorial.

This is the API code:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask
from flask import make_response
from flask import request
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
    
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)
  
@app.route('/5492946838458/index.html', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    if not request.json or not 'key' in request.json or not 'name' in request.json or not 'text' in request.json or not 'pack' in request.json:
        abort(400)
    if 'title' in request.json and type(request.json['title']) != unicode:
        abort(400)
    if 'description' in request.json and type(request.json['description']) is not unicode:
        abort(400)
    task = {
      'key': request.json['key'],
      'name': request.json['name'],
      'text': request.json['text'],
      'pack': request.json['pack']
    }
    return (200)
```

This is the URL I'm sending it to

```
https://my.websites.url.here/5492946838458/
```

and the json data I'm sending

```
{
"key": "key",
"name": "name",
"text": "text",
"pack": "pack"
}
```

and the headers I get back I get

```
date: Fri, 04 Sep 2020 17:48:30 GMT
content-length: 0
vary: Origin
accept-ranges: bytes
allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems I can see...

This line shouldn't be floating in the middle of your code.  It should be at the very end:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

With its current placement, if you're executing the app with `python app.py`, the app will run at this point.  Routes before it (`index`) will be available, however routes declared after it (`create_task`) will not (until you kill the server - when the latter route is added, right before the `python` process stops).

This problem wouldn't be seen if executing with `flask run` as the `if` clause is False.

---

`@app.route('/5492946838458/index.html', methods=['POST'])`

for this one you're probably want:

`@app.route('/5492946838458/', methods=['POST'])`

This declares the URL of that route.

Now a request to `https://my.websites.url.here/5492946838458/` should return a successful response.  A request to `/5492946838458` will return a 308 redirect to the one with the trailing slash.

I'm not sure why you were getting `405` before.  Perhaps there's aother route somewhere in your code accepting the request, but not the method.